# editing packages.config by hand

Tags: .net, package

i'm a .net/c# noob (long time java/servlet programmer)

i inherited an mvc 3 project and have been working on it for about 2 months. just opened packages.config for the first time and see jquery stuff in it:

```
<package id="jQuery" version="1.5.1" />
<package id="jQuery.vsdoc" version="1.5.1" />
<package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.8.0" />
<package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.8.11" />
```

my project has never used NuGet for anything. i understand this file is used by NuGet.

if i were to simply edit this file and remove lines from it, would there be any bad side-affects.

Comment: i appreciate your comment. however, i have never used nuget. sorta know what it's about. the link you provided also has links off to nuget dox. this doesn't really help in my case because i haven't used nuget myself. can i just remove the lines to packages i don't use?

Comment: You should not edit that file directly at all.

Comment: @horace: I understand except this is still a duplicate of the linked question either way. As the other answerers and the linked question reveal, this is related to nuget. If you rephrase your question differently, I'm sure it won't get closed.

Comment: **** In point of fact, I just edited the packages.config file to delete the offending lines BY HAND and it had no adverse side affects.  All that Bruhaha over nothing. Just edit it by hand. Too bad this topic is closed so I could answer my own question.

Comment: The fact is, if you have never used nuget yourself, you need to. Any of the modern project templates from the Asp.NET team use nuget packages as the way of adding the project dependencies so that you have an easy way of using the latest version of the libraries (which is particularly important with Javascript libraries, given the speed of development of browsers).

Answer (score 4):

It is the file used by [nuget](http://nuget.org/) to track what dependencies were installed.

Answer (score 1):

It's information about the NuGet packages that have been installed in the project via Visual Studio. It should not be edited manually.